# Join and max date with null values

Tags: sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, cognos, cognos-8

I need to return the most recent (max)date for a patient_ID where a vital value exists - it's not simply the max. encounter date for the patient_ID, it must have a corresponding vital value. I also only want encounters where vitals value <>'' and Date >= '2020-01-01' and vital_ID = 232268.

**Encounters (enc)**

| Patient_ID | Encounter_ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1/4/2020 |
| 1 | 12 | 1/15/2020 |
| 1 | 13 | 3/6/2020 |
| 2 | 14 | 1/12/2020 |
| 3 | 15 | 3/16/2020 |
| 3 | 16 | 4/19/2020 |
| 4 | 17 | 6/2/2020 |
| 4 | 18 | 6/12/2020 |
| 4 | 19 | 9/1/2020 |

**Vitals**

| Encounter_ID | Vital_ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 232268 | 4.8 |
| 12 | 232268 | 4.6 |
| 14 | 232268 | 3.1 |
| 16 | 232268 | 3.2 |
| 17 | 232268 | 4.1 |
| 18 | 232268 | 4.7 |

**Desired Outcome**

| Patient_ID | Encounter_ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 3/6/2020 | 4.6 |
| 2 | 14 | 1/12/2020 | 3.1 |
| 3 | 16 | 4/19/2020 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 18 | 9/1/2020 | 4.7 |

I tried this, but it returned only the vitals_encounter_ID IF it = max(date) of the encounter for the patient_ID (so did not include patient_ID if vitals were not taken on the max(date) - for instance, it negates patient_ID 1 all together because vitals weren't taken on encounter_ID 13:

```
select v.encounterID, e.patientID, e.date, v.value, v.vitalID 
from vitals v 
left join enc e on 
    e.encounterID = v.encounterID and 
    v.vitalID = 232268 and 
    v.value <> '' and
    e.date = (select max(date) from enc where patientID=e.patientID)
where e.date >= '2020-01-01'
```

Cognos 8. I'm new, so please don't eat me alive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you need the two tables in the correlated subquery:

```
select v.encounterid, e.patientid, e.date, v.value, v.vitalid 
from enc e 
inner join vitals v on v.encounterid = e.encounterid 
where 
    v.vitalid = 232268 
    and v.value <>'' 
    and e.date = (
        select max(e1.date) 
        from enc e1
        inner join vitals v1 on v1.encounterid = e1.encounterid 
        where 
            e1.patientid = e.patientid 
            and v1.vitalid = v.vitalid
            and v1.value <> ''
            and e.date >= '2020-01-01'
    )
```

I don't know if Cognos supports window functions. But if it does, the query can be much simpler phrased:

```
select *
from (
    select v.encounterid, e.patientid, e.date, v.value, v.vitalid,
        row_number() over(partition by e.patientid order by e.date)
    from enc e 
    inner join vitals v on v.encounterid = e.encounterid 
    where v.vitalid = 232268 and v.value <> ''
) t
where rn = 1
```